# How to fix "We don't execute document.execCommand() this time, because it is called recursively" execCommand delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, command, exec

I'm making a form with html5 and I'm validating the fields with jquery, what happens is that if in a text field I enter a number this is deleted immediately through the document.execCommand('delete') but I get this error in the console developer tools

```html
<input type="text" id="fieldText" placeholder="First name">
```

```
$('#fieldText').on('input', function(e){
    let keyPressedNow = e.originalEvent.data;
    if (keyPressedNow >= 0 && keyPressedNow <= 9) {
        if (document.execCommand("delete")) {
            console.log(e.originalEvent.data+' -successfully deleted')
        }
    }
```

`We don't execute document.execCommand() this time, because it is called recursively.`

what this mistake means and how can I fix it?